# Number of ways to color exactly K cells in a 3xN matrix such that no two colored cell are adjacent(do not share edges)?

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I tried to solve this problem using Dynamic Programming but it seems I am missing some cases that I am unable to find.

Here is the equation that I used for getting values from sub-problem

`dp[i][j] = dp[i][j-1] + 3*(dp[i-1][j-1] - dp[i-2][j-2]) + dp[i-3][j-2]`

(i = k = no of cells to be colored and j = n = number of columns, note the row is fixed i.e 3)

The terms are as defined below:

`dp[i][j-1]` : case when I don't color any cell in the nth column.

`dp[i-1][j-1] - dp[i-2][j-2]` : case when I color one cell in the last column and then have to subtract the case where I color the adjacent cell in the n-1th column and since this can be done for each of the 3 cells in the nth column I multiplied it with 3.

`dp[i-3][j-2]` : case when I color two cells(top and bottom ones) in the nth column and thus have only one choice for the n-1th column, that is the middle one, hence subtracting 3 from **i** and since we have already considered the last two columns I reduce 2 from **j**.

I couldn't find any mistake in the above approach, If you see any mistake please help.

Below is the actual question where an extra condition of P consecutive column not be empty is also mentioned and should be taken care of.

My approach is to first find all the possible ways to color k cells in 3xN matrix such that they are not adjacent and then finding the number of ways where P consecutive columns exist such that there are no cells colored in them and subtracting it with the total count, but in this approach, I'm missing the correct answer by a small margin for smaller inputs and a large margin for larger inputs. I must be missing something here.

[image: Actual question]

Comment: If you color two cells in the last column, there are two options for the previous column: one cell or no cells.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks, I forgot to include that case. Rest all cases are correct?

Comment: Please define "adjacent."

Comment: @גלעדברקן - adjacent means sharing a common edge, example:- adjacent cells of a(i, j) are a(i-1, j), a(i+1, j), a(i, j-1) and a(i, j+1)

Comment: Cool. Please share a link to the online judge if there is one.

Comment: @גלעדברקן - I don't have one, this was a part of a question in a contest that I was unable to solve using dynamic programming. So, wanted to know correct way to solve it, but if you want I can provied you with screenshot of the question that I took.

Comment: Maybe just some examples of larger input and correct expected output.

Comment: @גלעדברקן - actually there was an another condition mentioned in the question, that in coloring the cells as mentioned it should not count those ways in which there P consecutive column such that there are no cells colored in them, where P belongs to [1, 3], so with such cases I have some of the expected outputs.
for n = 50, k = 34 and p = 3 output is 720311466
for n = 90, k = 50 and p = 3 output is 985224274
for n = 200, k = 5000 and p = 1 output is 0

Comment: I thought of first finding the total number of ways and then subtracting the total ways where I keep P consecutive columns empty. But I'm missing the correct answer by a very small margin for small numbers and this margin keeps on increasing as I input larger values, so I must be either missing some of the cases in counting the total number of ways or maybe in finding the number of ways where P columns are empty.

Comment: @גלעדברקן - I'll add a screenshot to the question above.